# difference between web installer and nuget installer for asp.net mvc 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, installation

I want to install ASP.NET MVC 4, after a little googling I came across this two links

- http://www.asp.net/mvc/mvc4
- http://nuget.org/packages/aspnetmvc

Whats the difference between them ? As the first one prompts me that it needs Visual Studio 2010 SP1 which is approx 600+ Mb of download.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First will install MVC 3, [ASP.NET MVC 3 Tools Update](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2011/05/03/asp-net-mvc-3-tools-update.aspx) (also part of SP1) and other fixes and improvements. Second works only from Visual Studio and sometimes could give more problems for you or just fire error without any help. For example when you try to compile mvc3 project: [Installing MVC3 after MVC4 installation](http://surilpatel.wordpress.com/2012/08/01/installing-mvc3-after-mvc4-installation/comment-page-1/)